# What's wrong about this Bash one-liner?

Tags: bash

I'd be glad if you could point out, where I failed here:

```
line="some text"
printf "other text"|read line;printf '%s' "$line"
```

Output:

> some text

Output I had in mind:

> other text

Is this a subshell thing or am I missing something important?

Comment: your `read` command is executed in a subshell, so when this subshell exits (i.e., after the semi-colon), `line` recovers its previous value.

Comment: If you are running the latest `bash` (4.2 +), run `shopt -s lastpipe` to allow the `read` to run in the current shell, not a subshell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the pipe, the `$line` variable is assigned in a subshell, and the parent shell does not record the change. You can use the `shopt -s lastpipe` option to execute the last command of the pipeline in the current shell

In this example, where you only print a string, you can also use this syntax:

```
read line <<< "other text"; printf '%s' "$line"
```

Or in general you can use process substitution

```
read line < <(printf "other text"); printf '%s' "$line"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
read line < <(printf "other text") && printf '%s' "$line"
```